# I can't figure out why this while loop isn't functioning properly

Tags: python

```
integer1 = eval(input('Enter the first integer between -10 and 10: '))

integer2 = eval(input('Enter the second integer between -10 and 10: '))

while (integer1 >= 10 or integer1 <= -10):
    replace1 = eval(input('Integer 1 is invalid, Please enter a valid number: '))

while (integer2 > 10 or integer2 < -10):
    replace2 = input('Integer2 is invalid, Please enter a valid number: ')
```

Comment: Is this Python 3 or Python 2? Also, please explain not working. We cannot guess whats going wrong

Comment: What does "isn't functioning properly" mean to you?

Comment: sorry, I believe this is python 3 and the error is that the while loop continues to output the error even after a valid number is entered.

Comment: you didn't add the `=` to the second `while` loop:  `integer2 > 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you expected:

```
integer1 = eval(input('Enter the first integer between -10 and 10: '))

integer2 = eval(input('Enter the second integer between -10 and 10: '))

while (integer1 >= 10 or integer1 <= -10):
    integer1 = eval(input('Integer 1 is invalid, Please enter a valid number: '))

while (integer2 > 10 or integer2 < -10):
    integer2 = input('Integer2 is invalid, Please enter a valid number: ')
```

**Since the value of integer1 is not changed in first while loop it will act as a infinite loop**

Instead of eval you could use `int()` since there are some harmful effect on using `eval` stick with `int`

**Modified:**

```
integer1 = int(input('Enter the first integer between -10 and 10: '))

integer2 = int(input('Enter the second integer between -10 and 10: '))

while (integer1 >= 10 or integer1 <= -10):
    integer1 = int(input('Integer 1 is invalid, Please enter a valid number: '))

while (integer2 > 10 or integer2 < -10):
    integer2 = int(input('Integer2 is invalid, Please enter a valid number: '))
```

Comment: i changed replce1/2 with integer1/2 and got this new error, while (integer2 > 10 or integer2 < -10):

TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Comment: @IbrahimEl-Rayes try the modified method

Comment: sorry, im new to python(just started today) whats the modified method?

Comment: The code in the answer under the heading "Modfied."

Comment: Ok, i used the modified version and now it works! thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

```
while (integer1 >= 10 or integer1 <= -10):
    replace1 = eval(input('Integer 1 is invalid, Please enter a valid number: '))
```

You never change `integer1`, so if the condition is true, it is *always* true and it loops forever.

Assign to `integer1` rather than `replace1`. Similarly for the second.